# Adapt script to handle closing 1 modal and opening another

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Could use some help in adapting script to be able to close the currently displayed Modal and load a new Modal on button click. All while using a reusable modal framework loading PartialViews.

I know I'm missing something, just can't put my finger on what needs to be added.

To trigger the modal, I'm using an ActionLink (@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Details", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @data_modal = "" }))

```
 $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        window.location.href = "/home/Index";
                    } else {
                        $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
```

No problem displaying the initial modal, but the Edit button that should trigger a new modal, loads it as a new view and not as a modal.

looked at "Reload content in modal (twitter bootstrap)", similar to the script I'm using.

```
$("a[data-target=#myModal]").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    
    // load the url and show modal on success
    $("#myModal .modal-body").load(target, function() { 
         $("#myModal").modal("show"); 
    });
});
```

looked at "Jquery simplemodal close existing modal and open a new one?"
Came across "Best way to handle mutliple modals using Jquery and Bootstrap"

Concept Example of what I'm trying to do, but with a single modal frame and partialviews.

```
<style>
.modal:nth-of-type(even) {
    z-index: 1052 !important;
}
.modal-backdrop.show:nth-of-type(even) {
    z-index: 1051 !important;
}
</style>
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Detail View</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>    
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        </div><div class="container"></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Content for the modal #1 goes here.
          <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="myModal2" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">2nd Modal title</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        </div><div class="container"></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Content for the modal #2 goes here.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
          <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-danger" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$("#myModal2").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    $("#myModal").modal("hide")
})

$("#myModal2").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    $("#myModal").modal("show")
})

</script>
```

Comment: Where is the Edit button?

Comment: @76484 The Edit button would be on Details modal view and it would be an  ActionLink (as above).

Answer (score 0):

I do not develop with C# and I notice that you haven't posted the *form* part of your process.

Anyway, analyzing the JS code, I can suppose that you have a script that contains the form to show into the modal and perhaps the logic to handle it (validation, etc...) or otherwise the form has an action to redirect to the next script on *submit*.

If the form-script contains also the logic, you must specify an *action attribute* for the form that will be valued with a referral to his own script (something like *HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath* but as said I don't develop in C# and I can't confirm that it is the correct 'variable'): if this is missing, the action of the form is the address of the current page of the browser and this is why the page is reloaded.

Another potentially problem is that AJAX call in the *bindForm()* function expects either JSON data (when it's all right) either HTML data (in case there are errors or a successive phase to display, i suppose): to correctly manage the sent data, make sure you also send an header specifying the data type (I think it's enough to send a `Content-type: application/json` header when you send JSON) to allow the JQuery.ajax call to correctly manage the returned data. Otherwise you can specify the `dataType: 'json'` property in the AJAX call and send back always a JSON like: `{success: false, content: "<form>form-content</form>"}` or `{success: true, content: ""}` and change `$('#myModalContent').html(result);` with `$('#myModalContent').html(result.content);` in your code.

*Other things to note*

- In your code you close the modal (`$('#myModal').modal('hide');`) and right after you do a redirect: you can omit the closing of the modal
- After `$('#myModalContent').html(result);` there is a call to bindForm() itself, but it does nothing and can be removed

Comment: I tried the changes you recommended and thank you.. But the second partial view doesn't replace the original.  My prof of concept is just to have a parent view (index) that has a modal and when you launch the modal, you see partial view (details) and if you click the button, it switches the partial view(edit).  The final step is on submit, the modal popup returns the user to the parent view. The modal works as in it displays the initial partial view. But when you click the button, it replaces the parent view with the second partial view.

Comment: @Wondering Let's see if I understand. Main view *(index)* has a button (*$("a[data-modal]")* is it, right?). Clicking on the button you open a modal and fill it with a partial view loaded via AJAX (this i what I understand ): this process works. The partial in the modal has his own button which should start via AJAX the subsitution of the modal content with another partial containing a form. Submitting the form, the modal closes and/or the main index page is updated. Is it right?

Comment: you are correct.

Comment: @Wondering ok, then you should post "The partial in the modal [that] has its own button which should start via AJAX the subsitution of the modal content" because the problem seems related to this part which I don't see.There's one more thing I'm missing: following this reasoning, the `$("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {` event should display the first partial, instead it seems to handle the latter, by calling `bindForm(this);`

Comment: I'm trying to learn JS. Basically the first part is setting the stage for the modal and the second is passing information to the controller action.  If the result is the view it loads it into the modal, if it's the message success = true, it loads the Index.  If there's a better way to handle this, I'm all for it.

Comment: @Wondering I'll try to be clearer: `$("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {`
loads the form into the modal via AJAX and the `bindForm(dialog)` function sends the form data to a controller/action (whose URL is set in the *action* of the form) and then handles the returned result. In this scenario the part that manages/displays the *details* and that (as you said) contains the button that activates the loading of the form in the modal is missing. Can you post this missing part so I can analyze it?

Comment: The button used is the same, except it calls the Edit Action to display that partial view.  In reading only one Modal can be displayed at a time.. So I suspect code is need to close the currently open modal before calling the modal again with a new view.. I could have miss interpreting this.